# What after connecting AWS database and MYSQL WorkBench?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, connectivity

I need proper explanation and steps to connect to an RDS database from my AWS Elastic BeanStalk Project. I have already created a RDS instance on AWS and successfully connected to it from MYSQL Workbench. After that, I have also connected it to my Elastic BeanStalk project. But still my java based website project cannot fetch data from it. Why ????

Comment: Its application specific. You havn't provided any info about your application, no code, no error messages, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is documented here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker

This tutorial steps you through creating a Java Spring app that is deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and queries data from an RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can access your RDS instance from your elastic beanstalk environment when you set the RDS instance to public. If you can you have not configured your security groups to allow connections from your EB environments towards your rds instance.

Note: don't forget to set it to private again after you're done with testing.